# Create Dataframe froma text file

Tags: python, pandas

Basically i was processing below text file to format into below output

/* ----------------- A ----------------- */
F1: web_xample_example_of_job   F2: CMD
F3: check.sh
/* ----------------- B ----------------- */
F1: web_xample_example_of_job2  F2: CMD
F3: check2.sh
/* ----------------- C ----------------- */
F1: web_xample_example_of_job3  F2: CMD
F3: check3.sh
F4: New_File

[image: I want Output as]

the file look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJzDO.png)

Comment: the dataset is 

dataset = {'A': {'F1': 'web_xample_example1', 'F2': ' CMD'}}
{'B': {'F1': 'web_xample_example2', 'F2': ' CMD'}}
{'C': {'F1': 'web_xample_example3', 'F2': ' CMD', 'F3': ' New_File'}}

Comment: The posted `dataset` is not valid python datatype. You have list of dictionaries? Post `print(dataset)` output to the question.